# IF and CASE in insert query

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TBL (KPIName ,KPILabel)
SELECT  `d`.`si_kpi_name` AS `KPIName`, 
    IF(`t`.`kpi_val` = 0,
        WHEN (`v`.`TOIOS` >= `t`.`kpi1`) THEN 'Bad'
        WHEN (`v`.`TOIOS` >= `t`.`kpi2`) THEN 'Poor'
        WHEN (`v`.`TOIOS` >= `t`.`kpi3`) THEN 'Fair'
        ELSE 'GOOD',

        WHEN (`v`.`TOIOS` <= `t`.`kpi1`) THEN 'Bad'
        WHEN (`v`.`TOIOS` <= `t`.`kpi2`) THEN 'Poor'
        WHEN (`v`.`TOIOS` <= `t`.`kpi3`) THEN 'Fair'
        ELSE 'GOOD' )

        AS `KPILabel`
FROM (
    `voom_min` `v` LEFT OUTER JOIN `denver_config` `d` ON (`v`.`si_id` = `d`.`si_id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN gen_config g ON (d.si_name = g.si_name)
    JOIN `kpi_downstream` `t` ON ((`t`.`kpi` = 'market analysis'))
    )
WHERE (`v`.`TOIOS` IS NOT NULL)
```

---

MYSQL - Please concentrate on the part of where `KPILABEL` is calculated. What I am trying to do is:

If `T.KPI_VALUE == O`, Check set of conditions ... If not check set of conditions ...

I see in some websites the syntax of `IF` while using in insert query as

```
if(condition, if condition yes statements, ifnot statments)
```

I used this syntax for if syntax ...
for "if condition yes statements I used `CASE` statements"

Please help me to fix the syntax.

Comment: Using ALL CAPITALS is considered rude. I've updated your question and formatted the code, too, this time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix

```
CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result
          [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...]
          [ELSE result] END
```

and

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

syntaxes.

See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)